# Spectrum of Symmetrizable Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory

A matrix $ M $ is symmetrizable if $ M = D S $ with $ D $ a square diagonal matrix with positive entries, and $ S $ a symmetric matrix. What can be said about the spectrum of $ M $?

It seems like I can just define the inner product induced by $ D^{-1} $, ie $ \langle v, w \rangle  =  v^T D^{-1} w $, then recognize that $ M $ is hermitian under this inner product, and then apply the spectral theorem. But it has been a long day and I'm afraid I'm overlooking something, so a confirmation would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's right, although I assume you mean that $S$ is symmetric and real; otherwise, any complex number $z$ can appear in the spectrum of $M$ by setting, for example, $D=I, S = zI.$

If $v$ is a unit eigenvector of $M$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then
$$\lambda v^*D^{-1}v = v^*D^{-1}DSv = v^*Sv = v^*S^*v = v^*S^*D^*D^{-1}v = \lambda^*v^*D^{-1}v.$$

Since $D$ is Hermitian positive-definite, so is $D^{-1}$ and $v^*D^{-1}v \neq 0$, so
$$\lambda = \lambda^*$$
and $\lambda$ is real. Notice that the signs of the entries on the diagonal of $D$ aren't really relevant, as long as they are nonzero and real.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth noting that this only shows that the eigenvalues are real when the corresponding eigenvectors have finite norm: $v^*D^{-1}v<\infty$. Of course, this is only relevant when dealing with infinite dimensional matrices.